# Trying to feed a gz file to a c++ program

Tags: c++, command-line, gzip

I have a c++ program which has some command line options. One of them is the file name. The file size is big so I decided to compress it and then try to find a way that the c++ program read the compressed file instead of the plain text file.

According to what is stated here [How to read a .gz file line-by-line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201538/how-to-read-a-gz-file-line-by-line-in-c) I tried the second answer but it doesn't work.

Assume the normal command line for running my program is

```
 ./run 1 file.txt 10
```

Now I run

```
 zcat file.gz | ./run 1 file.gz 10
```

But the output is invalid. How can I fix that?

P.S:

The file looks like

```
10 1000
2   39
45 124
```

And the code which reads the file looks like

```
char *inp = argv[2];
std::ifstream fin (inp);
int a, b;
while (fin >> a >> b ) {
   // somthing
}
```

Comment: Can you change your program so it reads from STDIN instead of opening the given file name?

Comment: What do you mean? Using STDIN, I have to enter the input interactively. Right? Please see the updated post

Comment: `zcat` generates output on its STDOUT. The pipe `|` forwards this to the STDIN of your process. That's what pipes do.

Comment: ok I understand. So how can I change the program to meet that need? Can you post a reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest immediate fix in your situation is to change this:

```
char *inp = argv[2];
std::ifstream fin (inp);
int a, b;
while (fin >> a >> b ) {
  // something
}
```

into this:

```
char *inp = argv[2];
int a, b;
while (std::cin >> a >> b ) {
  // something
}
```

I've replaced `fin` with `std::cin`. You need to `#include <iostream>` for this if you haven't done so yet.

This will read from STDIN, which is where the pipe `|` sends the output of `zcat`.

If you want to keep both versions – one that reads from file and one that reads from STDIN – you could use a command line argument to indicate that you are reading from STDIN, and then have an `if`-clause in the code to distinguish between the two usages.