# tail a gzipped file in c++

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, gzip

I have multiple huge gzipped text files.
I have to read the first and last n lines without loading the whole file into memory using head and tail like functions.
For plain text files I use a tail like function similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17878200/3604468).

However I want to avoid unzipping the files first.
I have implemented a head like function working on gzipped files using a technique similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3201675/3604468).
But I fail to implement a tail like function that works with gzipped files.

Comment: The answer you reference actually *is* uncompressing the file. It just does it transparently (by pusing the `zlib_decompressor()` filter).

Comment: And what you want to accomplish isn't really possible without uncompressing the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done without running through the entire file and decompressing, at least in memory.

Comment: This is a pity.